# Using an apex:repeat variable in an if statement in visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have what seems like such a simple task.  I have a list that contains two integers (0,1).  I'm looping through that list in an apex:pageblockTable. Based on the value I want to render different things.  But it's not working.

Controller code

```
public List<Integer> m_lstNums {get;set;}{m_lstNums = new List<Integer>{0,1};}
```

Visualforce

```
 <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!m_lstNums}" var="keyValue">
  <apex:column  headerValue="Description">
    <apex:outputText value="{!If((keyValue == 0), '0','1')}"/>
  </apex:column>
 </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

If I change the outputText value to be

```
<apex:outputText value="{!keyValue}"/>
```

It outputs the 0 and 1 properly.  But the first set of code only displays the 1 both times.  Like keyValue never equals 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried below VF page code

```
<apex:page controller="Testabc">
    <apex:pageBlock title="My Content">

        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!m_lstNums}" var="keyValue">
            <apex:column  headerValue="Description">
                <apex:outputText value="{!If((keyValue == 0), '2','3')}"/>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Controller code:

```
public class Testabc {
public List<Integer> m_lstNums {get;set;}{m_lstNums = new List<Integer>{0,1};}

}
```

Below is the VF output and it works as you expect. Not sure if you have put all the information in the question

[image]

Comment: Thanks RedDevil.  I'm still not sure what is wrong.  But I commented out all the rest of the columns in my table and it works.  So now I'll just have to troubleshoot each column.